# Why does elongation occur

Tags: elasticity, stress-strain

Consider a rod having some mass. This rod is subjected to 2 equal and opposite forces ($F$) on both ends. Since these forces are equal and opposite the center of mass does not move. The rod, however, will be deformed.

The deformation of the rod is explained by the stress which is generated in the rod. This stress is calculate by dividing the tension $T$ in the rod by it's cross-section area $A$.

What confuses me is the fact that the tension acting on differential mass elements of the rod is equal and opposite (by the definition of tension). The rod (center of mass) is not moving but is getting deformed. This implies that there must be some Force imbalance between the internal forces.

In simpler words: I can't understand the reason for elongation in the rod since tension is equal and opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the net forces acting on an objects tells you how the object will move; but there are still internal reactions that can change the internal energy of the system without causing the center of mass to accelerate (i.e. no net force acts on it).

This is what stress is doing.  It's actually changing the magnitude of the internal forces that the rod exerts on itself; but the *net* forces are still balanced, so the rod doesn't move.  If, for example though, you were to remove the force on one end of the rod suddenly, you would find that the stored potential energy is indeed capable of applying a force onto something else.

Basically, as long as the forces cancel out, they don't lead to net movement of the centre of mass, but they still lead to changes in internal energy, which is consistent with deformation/elongation.

Comment: But what about the force on a small mass element. Are forces on left and right sides of it balanced as well ?

Comment: @AdityaAhuja If the element isn't moving, yes.

Comment: But the element is being elongated so it must have some Force imbalance.

Comment: @AdityaAhuja During the elongation, sure, there's force imbalances that led to it.  There has to be some imbalanced force in one direction to get it to start moving, and in the opposite direction to get it to stop again.  Even then though, the average force would just be the tension force.  Once internal forces equalize , the system stops moving, and there's still internal energy/stress in the rod regardless.

Comment: I asked my professor about this and he explained It to me by telling me to consider every small mass element of the string to be a small string itself with Tension Force on either sides of it. This means that the small mass element is not moving but is getting elongated. This means that the entire string has tension and is also at rest. Is this correct ?